# Visual Studio 2015 Taks runner explorer causing multiple node.exe processes

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, npm, gulp

I'm using **`gulp`** to build a website project. Within **Visual Studio 2015** the **task runner explorer** picks up the gulp file and I can run tasks from there. The problem is: this spins up multiple `node.exe` processes (sometimes more than 20), drastically slowing down my machine.

None of the `node.exe` processes takes up too much memory (about 100mb each) or CPU, but combined they manage to choke all cores.

Just firing up Visual Studio already causes the problem, I don't even need to run the tasks from Task Runner Explorer.

When Visual Studio is shut down, and I run some gulp tasks from the command line, the issue does not occur.

Any thoughts on this? Or people with the same problem?

I don't think there is a problem with the gulp file itself, but if necessary, I can provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of Web Tools (.NET Core Tooling Preview 1) improved this behavior. The tools used to make several command line calls to get information about Bower and npm packages, as well as Gulp and Grunt tasks. Now most of those calls are consolidated into a single `node.exe` process.

If you can, try the new version from here: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798481

If you're using the latest version and still seeing this behavior, can you provide more information about your solution? How many projects does it have, and how many of those have bower.json, package.json, gulpfile.js, or gruntfile.js files?

Comment: I am seeing this with VS2017 v15.3.5. We just implemented gulp in our legacy ASP.NET MVC 5 application, just to watch a few CSS files and rebuild them when they were modified.  But VS is spinning up 5-6 node.js processes with sizes ranging from 26M to 380M (probably the streaming one that watches the files). There seems to be a Console Window Host process for each one @3.5M each. With Visual Studio and Sql Developer running, I'm hittin 82% on the box. It does have about 25 projects, but only one (the only ASP.NET web project) has a gulpfile.js and a package.json.